# Refactoring Menu Not Showing in Visual Studio 2012 RC

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

The refactoring menu isn't showing up for me in Visual Studio 2012 RC. It's not showing in the menu bar or in the context sensitive help. Is there a setting I need to change to make it appear. I see the refactor menu in the customize option but can't make it show up in the menu bar. This is in a c# project.

Comment: You still can get the refactor menu by right click on code.

Comment: Not sure if you have found it yet. If you are using Resharper already, you could use Resharper > Refactor.

Comment: One of the causes a right click doesn't show the Refactor command in the context menu is, that the file will not be build. Ensure the file's property `Build Action` is set to `Compile`.

Answer (score 6):

I had this happen to me just now. Turned out I was editing a file that wasn't part of the open solution -- it was from another branch. Confused the heck out of me until I realized that.

Comment: Sure enough, my file was excluded from the solution somehow. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar instance.  Turns out, the project I was working on doesn't always have some of the files set to compile.  In this case, it was an ASMX file, and none of the refactor bits worked.